# AWS Serverless: configure multiple frontend apps under one domain

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, next.js, serverless-framework

I have two frontend apps. First one uses Static Generation (for SEO purposes), and the Second one uses Client Side Rendering (for all stuff behind auth flow).

I want to have both of them under the same purchased domain, with the base endpoints to be something like:

1. `mydomain.com\public\*` : for all my public facing statically generated content using the first App.
2. `mydomain.com\auth\*`: for all the stuff that lies behind the auth flow.. made using the second app.

**So the question is:**
How to map these two separate apps to two base endpoints under the same domain? I was reading this post [Share an API Endpoint Between Services](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/share-an-api-endpoint-between-services.html), but it seemed to be for the backend.

In case anyone is interested to know why two separate apps: 
It's because the Static generation is done using Next.js, while the Client side stuff is done using simple create-react-app. [This post](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/14020#discussioncomment-24558) explains why this combination needs to be separately deployed.

Comment: I don't understand why you need two apps for this. Both static generation and CSR for different routes are possible within the same NextJS app.

Comment: @AnkitGupta I know. But both these apps are already developed quite a bit. hence we want to avoid porting one app into another

Answer (score 3):

Refer to [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/dynamically-route-viewer-requests-to-any-origin-using-lambdaedge/)

[image]

Create two separate s3 buckets for your NextJs and React app. Attach them to a CloudFront distribution. Attach a lambda function to your CloudFront distribution and route requests to different origin based on whether the `request.uri.startsWith('/public')` or not.